# Different nvidia driver versions per docker container

Tags: gpu, nvidia-docker

Is it possible to run two Nvidia Docker containers, each with its own Nvidia driver version?

On my cloud instance, I have an older application running for which newer Nvidia drivers are causing issues. I'd like the ability to keep running it with the older driver, while allowing newer applications on the same instance to use newer drivers. I was thinking I could accomplish this with containers but I'm worried that they only allow you to containerize things in user space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. The driver is installed on the host.

These articles:
[NVIDIA Docker: GPU Server Application Deployment Made Easy](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/nvidia-docker-gpu-server-application-deployment-made-easy/)
and the newer
[Enabling GPUs in the Container Runtime Ecosystem](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/gpu-containers-runtime/)
discuss how the stack is set up.

The key takeaway is that Nvidia brings their own version of runc (the part of Docker that actually runs the container process). This modified version of runc communicates with the host OS to make driver-level details available to the container process.

EDIT (Oct 2022): I believe this answer is outdated. Nvidia/Docker have since released Driver Containers which allow provisioning of the driver as a container. The only thing that's needed is the Nvidia Container Toolkit and some light configuration. See [this link](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/driver-containers/overview.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answering for an update, actually now its possible to different driver version inside different containers. All you have to do is change the NVIDIA Container Toolkit config file (/etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml) so that the root directive points to the driver container as shown below:

```
disable-require = false
swarm-resource = "DOCKER_RESOURCE_GPU"

[nvidia-container-cli]
root = "/run/nvidia/driver"
path = "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-cli"
environment = []
debug = "/var/log/nvidia-container-toolkit.log"
ldcache = "/etc/ld.so.cache"
load-kmods = true
no-cgroups = false
user = "root:video"
ldconfig = "@/sbin/ldconfig.real"

[nvidia-container-runtime]
debug = "/var/log/nvidia-container-runtime.log"
```

This command can be directly used to make this modification :

```
$sudo sed -i 's/^#root/root/' /etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml
```

After that you can run a container with a required version of driver in background using :

```
$sudo docker run --name nvidia-driver -d --privileged --pid=host \
  -v /run/nvidia:/run/nvidia:shared \
  -v /var/log:/var/log \
  --restart=unless-stopped \
  nvidia/driver:450.80.02-ubuntu18.04
```

and then run the GPU conatiner with required version of CUDA for your work:

```
$sudo docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0-base nvidia-smi
```

Answer (score -1):

Containers are for isolating the processes. Only the host's kernel is same for all containers, which is not the case for virtual machine. So you can create one container for old application with older driver and another container for new application with new nvidia driver. Containers are meant for this.

But for nvidia docker you may require 1 gpu per pod, but this can be bypassed using some simple methods, which is  not a good solution

Comment: But containers are a user space phenomenon, while drivers operate in kernel space. What you are suggesting means that you have to install driver-related software in the container. How would this be possible? I'm looking at [this link](https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/07/29/architecting-containers-part-1-user-space-vs-kernel-space/).