# Is it possible to use newer nvidia drivers to run pytoch code with previous version nvidia drivers on the same host?

Tags: docker, pytorch, gpu, driver, nvidia

I have a host with windows server (with some GPUs) which is used as a part of Distributed Calculation Framework. There 412 Nvidia Driver is installed. How I understand this driver version is necessary to run some application for distributed calculation.

I would like to run some pytorch code. But the 412 driver is too old and I would like to use more newer driver. Is it possible not to crash current settings and current driver (412) to use newer driver to run pytorch 2.*?

There is a topic with similar question but assosiated with dockers. I don't understand is docker may be useful for my task because I haven't used it before. [Different nvidia driver versions per docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649214/different-nvidia-driver-versions-per-docker-container)

Also, I have found the documentation about nvidia compability https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/. But it is not clear for me how to resolve my problem.